# Using HtmlHelper.BeginForm Extension Method To Prepend To URL Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.beginform

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 4 application that makes use of the [HtmlHelper.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) methods within the views. This site is now going to sit behind a reverse proxy which will add prepend some characters into the path part of the URL. I was hoping to create an extension method to HtmlHelper that would allow me to do the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "MyControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "my-class" })){
```

And be able to modify the output from:

```
<form method="POST" action="/MyController/ActionName" class="my-class">
```

to the following instead:

```
<form method="POST" action="/Some/Prepended/Path/MyController/ActionName" class="my-class">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FormExtensions.BeginRouteForm` method to achieve this.

First, create a route in `RouteConfig` class like below:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "FormRoute",
    url: "Some/Prepended/Path/{controller}/{action}"
    );
```

then use `Html.BeginRouteForm`

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("FormRoute", new { }, 
         FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "my-class" })){}
```

Finally, you can call your action method like below:

```
http://localhost:57744/Some/Prepended/Path/YourController/YourAction
```

For more details about FormExtensions.BeginRouteForm Method, see below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505047(v=vs.118).aspx